# Python while-loop & List qestion

Tags: python, while-loop

I want the program to take in the number by input (like school grades) and calculate the average. But it should quit when I put in the grade 0.

like:

```
Grade:3
Grade:5
Grade:0
The average grade is 3.86


while  1<2:
    x = input("Grade:")
        x += x        #unsure about the algoritm
break x = 0
      y=x/?            #how to count the amont of loops
      print "The average grade is",y
```

Comment: Your code is _completely_ broken.  Is this simply an attempt to demonstrate _attempt_?

Comment: `x+=x;` does it work given how you take the input?

Comment: You look *very* new to Python & programming in general. First take your time to [read through this](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) before attempting to actually complete a task. Right now, it's a bit like you're trying to do the LeMans without first getting your driver's license. The book *Learning Python*, by Mark Lutz is also very good for beginning programmers (but not free, and there are other books as well).

Answer (score 2):

As it looks like homework, I'll show you the concepts.

1. You have to sum up the values in a separate variable which you set to 0 at the start. You do the same with another variable where you count.

   Put the commands

   ```
   total = 0
   count = 0
   total += x
   count += 1
   ```

   where they seem useful.
2. Fix your indenting.
3. This is not how `break` works. Instead, put it as a command in an `if` clause where you check the value of `x`.

Comment: +1 for guiding and not writing a full code.